# Archive Xamarin.Forms Android project from command line with msbuild

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, msbuild

For Xamarin.Forms iOS project, the following command seems to work :

```
msbuild /p:Configuration='Release' /p:Platform='iPhone' /p:IpaPackageDir=<DIRECTORY FOR IPA TO LIVE> /t:Build '../SampleApp.sln' /p:BuildIpa=true /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true
```

Is there any such parameter like "ArchiveOnBuild" for archiving android projects?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't defined the following properties in your csproj file, then you would need to supply them as MSBuild arguments:

- AndroidKeyStore = True
- AndroidSigningKeyAlias = Your keystore alias
- AndroidSigningKeyPass = keystore password
- AndroidSigningKeyStore = path to keystore
- AndroidSigningStorePass = keystore password

Then you can run your build with the targets

- Build
- SignAndroidPackage

So something like:

```
/p:AndroidKeyStore=True /p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=herpa /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=hunter2 /p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=/my/path/to/app.keystore /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=hunter2 /t:Build;SignAndroidPackage
```

Then after the build the APK or AAB should be in the bin/Release folder of your App project.